# T-SQL daily backup of data based off a date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, archive

I have 2 tables that are identical, event and event_1. Each day I want to insert the new records added to the event table into event_1 table.

Below is a SQL statement of what I want to do but I don't know the proper SQL to do it. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
select * 
into event_1 
from Event 
where Event.EventDate > max(event_1.eventdate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to be exactly the same maybe just truncate and fill the table.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE event_1

INSERT INTO event_1
SELECT *
FROM event
```

Or maybe something like this using `not exists`.

```
INSERT INTO event_1 
SELECT *
FROM event e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM event_1 e1 WHERE e1.eventdate = e.eventdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO event_1 --(column list)
SELECT * --(column list)
FROM Event
WHERE Event.EventDate > max(event_1.eventdate)
```

Use column lists instead of * when possible.  If your tables are exactly the same * will work, but it is a bad practice.

If they are in different databases on the same server you have to fully qualify the tables ie "DB_Name.schema.Event", if on different servers you need linked server with permissions and have to use 4 part qualifying ie "Server.DB_Name.schema.Event"

Comment: I get the following error when executing this. The multi-part identifier "event_1.eventdate" could not be bound.

Comment: Try aliasing both tables.  Also, double check the table names and column name, I pulled that phrase directly from what was in the original question.